# Horizontal html list going vertical

Tags: html, css

So, I have been trying to create a horizontal navigation bar for a website of mine. I went ahead, tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - It worked fine. Then my friend went ahead and tested it in Internet Explorer and this happened - http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/d8/d84069e1bba73593afc0764935a2aa6d.png

(Yes I know it is not IE, yet it is 100% the same as what happened to him)

The links on the navigation bar are being pushed down into a vertical list. Why is this?\

CSS -

```
div#menu
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    top:0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: url("../Images/NavBar.png");
}

div#navBar
{
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    zindex:1001;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
}

ul#menuItems
{
    background:none;
    height:50px;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul#menuItems li
{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:0px;
    height:50px;
    padding-right:10px;
    min-width:65px;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="navBar">
        <ul id="menuItems">
            <li>
              <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">DJ Profiles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Chat Room</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input name="searchField" type="text" value="Search Users" size="60" maxlength="150" id="SearchBox"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Login to S4NR</a>
            </li>
<!--            <li id="userInfo">
                <p align="center" style="font-size:11px;">Welcome, Username.</p>
            </li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because older IE-s don't care about `display: inline-block`. You have to float your menu items `float: left`

Comment: Just a hint: You don't need to fix position on elements of already fixed positioned parants.

Comment: Zoltan is correct. Plus list style none on the ul itself, I believe. Also might help to set a width on the li items. Play around with it in Chrome inspector or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, inline-block CAN be an issue with older IEs, but that's not all the going wrong here, and honestly depending on where you are most places you don't have to worry about IE5,6,and probably even 7 anymore.

```
ul#menuItems li
{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:0px;
    height:50px;
    padding-right:10px;
    min-width:65px;
}
```

Most browsers are going to take conflict with the combination of flexible margins AND flexible width above.  Almost always you'll end up with the element taking up close to 100% of the navbar width.  If you know for sure how many list items you will have, I suggest giving them a fixed or percentage based width, removing the margin attributes, and centering the internal links with `text-align: center;`  This will give you the same effect with far fewer headaches.

If you decide to try to fix older IE, add `float: left; position: relative;`